# Dealing with int arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

I was looking at some c++ code as I am trying to learn it and came across something strange and I have no clue what is going on.

```
int A[100000];

int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", A + i);
    }
```

I understand everything that is happening except for the `scanf("%d", A + i);` line
what is happen­ing to the array here? is it just adding the integer read in from the console to the array? I have a good understanding of Java.

So if someone would be able to translate that to Java. I would most likely be able to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 5):

`A + i` is the same as `&A[i]`, or in other words, `A[i]` is the same as `*(A + i)`. So `A + i` is the address of the i<sup>th</sup> element (count starting at zero).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the term array-to-pointer-conversion.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hm, it's really more of the other way around: Pointer arithmetic allows you to treat any object pointer as a pointer to an element of an array...

Comment: Have to sort-of disagree. It's the conversion of `A` to `&A[0]` that makes `A + i` a valid expression, so I think it's desirable to mention it. But meh, your answer, your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this doesn't translate very well to Java. It is an example of *pointer arithmetic*, which only makes sense when you understand that pointers and arrays are numbers just like any others. `A + i` stands for "the memory address `i` units beyond `A`". (In this case, the units are `int`s, which are 4 bytes. So you could also write it as "the memory address `i * 4` *bytes* beyond `A`".)

Comment: Arrays are not numbers. Arrays are not pointers. Ints are not necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right, but in his context his array is equivalent to a pointer, so I thought it was appropriate to say they are equivalent for this particular question. And ints are almost always 4 bytes on a modern compiler. I'm not trying to create a 100% rigorous textbook definition, only to make it clearer for someone trying to learn the language.

Comment: War is peace. Freedom is slavery. Arrays are pointers. I can see *four* bytes.